# União de vetores, somando os vetores?

Tags: c

Criei a seguinte função para unir dois vetores (não podendo repetir um número igual), segue a função e os comentários mostrando o que fiz e o erro que esta dando:

```
void uniao(int *A, int *B, int qnt)
{
    int  C[qnt*2], cont, cont2, pos = 0, dif = 0;
    for(cont = 0; cont < qnt; cont ++)
    {
        C[cont] = 0; // zera o vetor do resultado
    }
    for(cont = 0; cont < qnt; cont ++)
    {
        for(cont2 = 0; cont2 < qnt; cont2 ++)
        {  // compara cada numero do vetor A com todos os numeros do vetor B
            if(A[cont] != B[cont2]) // se for diferente ele incrementa um contador
                dif += 1;
        }
        if(dif == (qnt))
        { // se ele for único (diferente de todos os outros numeros do outro vetor
            C[pos] = A[cont]; // ele armazena em um novo vetor
            pos += 1; // muda a posição desse novo vetor
        }
        dif = 0; // redefine o contador
    }
    /* 
        aqui é a parte que não funcina, primeiro eu armazenei só os números que não
        são repitidos do vetor A, agora para completar a união, basta adicionar ao vetor C
        todos elementos do vetor B (cujo não serão repitidos), porém preciso adicionar esses
        elementos nas posições posteriores do que li ali no for anterior, por isso a variavel pos
        agora varro todos elementos do vetor após a última posição que adicionei e atribuo o valor de B a ela,
        porem como o cont começa do pos, ele não vai pegar os 'pos' primeiros elementos do vetor B, como resolvo
        isso? Tentei colocar outro for dentro dele mas não entendi muito bem
    */
    for(cont = pos ; cont < qnt*2; cont ++ )
    {
            C[cont] = B[cont];
    }
}
```

No caso ele não pega x primeiras posições do vetor B pois igualei o cont á pos. Uma solução que pensei seria igualar la no primeiro for, todos elementos de c igual a nulo (mas não sei como faço isso) e depois fazer um if para preencher somente os elementos nulos, porém como atribuo nulo a um vetor int? Pois 0 pode dar um resultado errado, pois o vetor A ou B pode ter um algarismo 0

Comment: Não está claro o que precisa fazer... O vetor resultado não pode ter nenhum número repetido, ou não pode repetir números consecutivos ([1,2,3,2,1] é aceitável?). Você está comparando os elementos da mesma posição nos vetores de entrada, mas não parece ser o que você queria fazer.

Comment: Os números só não podem ser repetidos, a ordem não importa, pois depois vou ordenar, o que quero é a união de vetores, exemplo, A= 1, 2, 4, 5, 8 e B= 1, 2, 3, 5, 9 a união seria A U B= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, nesse caso a ordem foi automática pois os vetores A e B já estavam ordenados, mas é simplesmente pegar todos os números dos dois vetores e jogar em um vetor e retirar os números iguais, só que fiz ao contrário, primeiro retirei os números iguais e depois ia colocar os outros elementos..

Comment: Consegui alterar um pouco, colocando um cont2 no ultimo for e C[cont] = B[cont2]; apos isso coloquei cont2 += 1; Daí a saída foi: C=8, 4, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 8, 2, 5.. Ou seja ele pegou lixo, pois era pra exibir somente ate o 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que este código funciona. Um tanto diferente da lógica que você propôs...

```
void uniao(int *A, int *B, int qnt)
{
    int  C[qnt*2], i,j, contResultado;
    bool novoA, novoB;

    contResultado=0;
    for(i= 0; i< qnt; i++)
    {
        novoA=true;
        novoB=true;


        //Percorre o vetor resultao até a última posição, para ver se os números
        //da posição atual já existem 
        for(j=0;j<contResultado;j++)
        {
           if(C[j]==A[i])
               novoA=false;
           //Se o valor da posição atual do vetor B já existir, ou se for igual
           //ao valor do vetor A, ele não deve ser inserido.
           if(C[j]==B[i] || B[i]==A[i])
               novoB=false;
        }

        if(novoA)
        {
             C[contResultado]=A[i];
             contResultado++;
        }
        if(novoB)
        {
             C[contResultado]=B[i];
             contResultado++;
        }
    }
    //Zera o restante do vetor resultado
    for(i=contResultado+1;i<qnt;i++)
        C[i]=0;
}
```